# Поломалась верстка отслеживаемого знака по метке

Tags: дефект

В профиле в разделе "Активность" в блоке "Репутация" кнопка выбора отслеживания знака/привилегии "наезжает" на гистограмму прогресса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ассоциация: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296610/357761

Comment: Эту ошибку [уже починили к следующей пересборке](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296604/357761).